# Unsure how to implement an iterative function using aesara.scan()

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

I am new to the aesara package and I am using this package to implement a Bayesian Regression Model for market mix with the help of the PyMC library (Version : 5.9.2). My implementation is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import randint

# Generate date range
dates = pd.date_range(start="2021-01-01", end="2021-12-12")

data = {
    "date": dates,
    "gcm_direct_Impressions": [randint(10000, 20000) for _ in dates],
    "tv_grps": [randint(30, 50) for _ in dates],
    "tiktok_direct_Impressions": [randint(10000, 15000) for _ in dates],
    "sell_out_quantity": [randint(150, 250) for _ in dates]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#df.to_csv("dataset.csv", index=False)

max(df['sell_out_quantity'].values)


# Assigning the 'final_data' dataset to a new variable 'data' for further analysis.
import pandas as pd

data = df

# Defining a list of variables for transformation. These include various factors that 
# might impact the analysis like trends, seasons, holidays, competitor sales, and different 
# marketing channels.
transform_variables = ["gcm_direct_Impressions","tv_grps","tiktok_direct_Impressions"]

# Identifying the channels that have a delay effect. This means the impact of these channels 
# on the target variable (like revenue) might not be immediate but delayed.
delay_channels = ["gcm_direct_Impressions","tv_grps","tiktok_direct_Impressions"]

# Listing the media channels that are part of the analysis. These are the channels through 
# which advertising or marketing is done.
media_channels = ["gcm_direct_Impressions","tv_grps","tiktok_direct_Impressions"]

# Specifying the control variables. These are the factors that need to be controlled or 
# accounted for in the analysis to isolate the effects of the media channels.
#control_variables = ["trend", "season", "holiday", "competitor_sales_B", "events"]

# Defining the target variable for the analysis, which in this case is 'revenue'. This is 
# likely the outcome or the dependent variable the analysis aims to predict or explain.
target = "sell_out_quantity"

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Creating a copy of the 'data' dataframe to apply transformations. This ensures that 
# the original data remains unchanged.
data_transformed = data.copy()

# Initializing a dictionary to store the MinMaxScaler instances for each feature. 
# This will be useful for inverse transformations later.
numerical_encoder_dict = {}

# Looping through each feature in the list of variables to transform.
for feature in transform_variables:
    # Initializing a MinMaxScaler. This scaler transforms each feature to a given range, 
    # usually between 0 and 1, which is helpful for normalization.
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()

    # Reshaping the data for the feature into a 2D array, as required by the scaler.
    original = data[feature].values.reshape(-1, 1)

    # Applying the scaler to the feature and transforming the data.
    transformed = scaler.fit_transform(original)

    # Storing the transformed data back into the 'data_transformed' DataFrame.
    data_transformed[feature] = transformed

    # Saving the scaler instance in the dictionary for each feature. 
    # This will be used for reversing the transformation if needed.
    numerical_encoder_dict[feature] = scaler

# Placeholder for a potential dependent variable transformation, not utilized here.
dependent_transformation = None

# Scaling the target variable 'revenue' by dividing it by 100,000. 
# This kind of scaling might be done to bring the target variable to a smaller range 
# or to improve the interpretability of the model's results.
original = data[target].values
data_transformed[target] = original



import aesara
import aesara.tensor as tt

import numpy as np
def saturation_hill_pymc3(x, alpha, gamma): 
    # The Saturation-Hill function, often used in marketing mix modeling to represent 
    # diminishing returns on a variable (like advertising spend).
    # 'x' is the input variable (e.g., marketing spend).
    # 'alpha' and 'gamma' are parameters of the model.
    # This function returns a value between 0 and 1, representing the saturation level.
    x_s_hill = x ** alpha / (x ** alpha + gamma ** alpha)
    return x_s_hill



def adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x, theta):
    # Convert x to a Theano tensor if it's not already
    
    x = tt.as_tensor_variable(x)
    #x = aesara.shared(x)

    def step(current, previous, decay):
        return current + decay * previous

    # The first element of x_decayed is the same as the first element of x
    outputs_info = [dict(initial=x[0], taps=[-1])]

    # Use aesara.scan for iterative calculation
    x_decayed, _ = aesara.scan(
        fn=step,
        sequences=x[1:],
        outputs_info=outputs_info,
        non_sequences=theta
    )


    # aesara scan does not output the initial value, so it's prepended here
    return tt.concatenate([[x[0]], x_decayed])

import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

# Initializing an empty list to store the mean response from different channels and control variables.
response_mean = []

# Creating a new PyMC3 model context. All the model definitions inside this block 
# are part of 'model_2'.
with pm.Model() as model_2:
    # Looping through each channel in the list of delay channels.
    for channel_name in delay_channels:
        print(f"Delay Channels: Adding {channel_name}")

        # Extracting the transformed data for the current channel.
        x = data_transformed[channel_name].values
        
        # Defining Bayesian priors for the adstock, gamma, and alpha parameters for the current channel.
        adstock_param = pm.Beta(f"{channel_name}_adstock", 2, 2)
        saturation_gamma = pm.Beta(f"{channel_name}_gamma", 2, 2)
        saturation_alpha = pm.Gamma(f"{channel_name}_alpha", 3, 1)
        
        # Applying the adstock transformation to the channel data.
        # x_new = adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x, adstock_param)
        print(type(x))
        x_new = adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x,adstock_param)
        x_new_sliced = x_new



        # Applying the saturation transformation using the Hill function.
        saturation_tensor = saturation_hill_pymc3(x_new_sliced, saturation_alpha, saturation_gamma)
        
        # Defining a prior for the media effect coefficient of the channel.
        channel_b = pm.HalfNormal(f"{channel_name}_media_coef", sd = 250)

        # Calculating the response mean for the channel and adding it to the list.
        response_mean.append(saturation_tensor * channel_b)
        
    # Looping through each control variable.
#     for control_var in control_variables:
#         print(f"Control Variables: Adding {control_var}")

#         # Extracting the transformed data for the control variable.
#         x = data_transformed[control_var].values
        
#         # Defining a prior for the control coefficient.
#         control_beta = pm.Normal(f"{control_var}_control_coef", sd = 3)

#         # Calculating the contribution of the control variable.
#         control_x = control_beta * x
#         response_mean.append(control_x)
        
    # Defining a prior for the intercept of the model.
    intercept = pm.Normal("intercept", np.mean(data_transformed[target].values), sd = 3)
    
    # Defining a prior for the standard deviation of the model.
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", 4)
    
    # Defining the likelihood function of the model. 
    # This is where the model combines all the predictors and compares it to the observed target variable.
    likelihood = pm.Normal("outcome", mu = intercept + sum(response_mean), sd = sigma, 
                           observed = data_transformed[target].values)
```

I am getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 25
     22 # Applying the adstock transformation to the channel data.
     23 # x_new = adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x, adstock_param)
     24 print(type(x))
---> 25 x_new = adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x,adstock_param)
     26 x_new_sliced = x_new
     30 # Applying the saturation transformation using the Hill function.

Cell In[9], line 29, in adstock_geometric_theano_pymc3(x, theta)
     26 outputs_info = [dict(initial=x[0], taps=[-1])]
     28 # Use aesara.scan for iterative calculation
---> 29 x_decayed, _ = aesara.scan(
     30     fn=step,
     31     sequences=x[1:],
     32     outputs_info=outputs_info,
     33     non_sequences=theta
     34 )
     37 # aesara scan does not output the initial value, so it's prepended here
     38 return tt.concatenate([[x[0]], x_decayed])

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pymc_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aesara/scan/basic.py:464, in scan(fn, sequences, outputs_info, non_sequences, n_steps, truncate_gradient, go_backwards, mode, name, profile, allow_gc, strict, return_list)
    462 for elem in wrap_into_list(non_sequences):
    463     if not isinstance(elem, Variable):
--> 464         non_seqs.append(at.as_tensor_variable(elem))
    465     else:
    466         non_seqs.append(elem)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pymc_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aesara/tensor/__init__.py:49, in as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim, **kwargs)
     17 def as_tensor_variable(
     18     x: TensorLike, name: Optional[str] = None, ndim: Optional[int] = None, **kwargs
     19 ) -> "TensorVariable":
     20     """Convert `x` into an equivalent `TensorVariable`.
     21 
     22     This function can be used to turn ndarrays, numbers, `ScalarType` instances,
   (...)
     47 
     48     """
---> 49     return _as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim, **kwargs)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pymc_env/lib/python3.11/functools.py:909, in singledispatch.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kw)
    905 if not args:
    906     raise TypeError(f'{funcname} requires at least '
    907                     '1 positional argument')
--> 909 return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)

File ~/miniconda3/envs/pymc_env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aesara/tensor/__init__.py:56, in _as_tensor_variable(x, name, ndim, **kwargs)
     52 @singledispatch
     53 def _as_tensor_variable(
     54     x: TensorLike, name: Optional[str], ndim: Optional[int], **kwargs
     55 ) -> "TensorVariable":
---> 56     raise NotImplementedError(f"Cannot convert {x!r} to a tensor variable.")

NotImplementedError: Cannot convert gcm_direct_Impressions_adstock to a tensor variable.
```

Initially the tensor operations used to be taken care of by the theano package. How can I change the aesara.scan() code snippet to ensure that the iterative operation works? This function should be akin to the following implemented in numpy

```
def adstock_geometric_numpy(x, theta):
    """
    NumPy implementation of the geometric adstock transformation.

    :param x: NumPy array containing the input data (e.g., marketing spend over time).
    :param theta: Decay parameter for the adstock effect.
    :return: NumPy array with the adstock-transformed values.
    """
    # Initialize an array to store the adstock-transformed values
    x_decayed = np.zeros_like(x)
    
    # The first element remains the same as the original series
    x_decayed[0] = x[0]

    # Apply the adstock transformation to each element
    for i in range(1, len(x)):
        x_decayed[i] = x[i] + theta * x_decayed[i - 1]

    return x_decayed
```

Thanks in advance!